# Remove spaces between html fields when they are validated

Tags: css, jquery-validate

How I can remove spaces between fields when they are validated?

**Before Validation**

[image]

**After validation**

[image]

My Css

```
.field-validation-error {
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 8pt;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;   
   text-align: right;
   right: 5px;
   top: -26px;        
}

.input-validation-error {
   border: 1px solid #ff0000;
   background-color: #ffeeee;
}
```

Comment: provide a working example of this with jsfiddle or something similar.

Comment: **Show the relevant JavaScript and HTML markup!**  If you properly used the `errorPlacement` option, you wouldn't have this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my assumption is that your fields themselves are not `inline-block`

provide html source for your view.

or try using `float:left` instead of `display:inline-block` in your `.field-validation-error` class